# Inner Join Error joining two tables - small syntax error I'm assuming

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo, inner-join

I have a tickets table and a customers table.  I'm trying to take basic information from the tickets table, and simply add the clientDisplayName field from the customers table that corresponds to the the clientID field in the ticket table.

I also need to verify whether the where clause is right, I only want it to return ticket info where the ticketstatus IS NOT EQUAL to "closed"  Should I use <> or IS NOT EQUAL TO?

I'm getting a #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT t.id, t.clientID, c.clientDisplayName, t.ticketTitle t.ticketDueDate t.t' at line 1

Here's my query, I just started using PDO, but I believe my issue is just with the join as I'm new to that also:

```
$conn->prepare("SELECT 
                    t.id, 
                    t.clientID, 
                    c.clientDisplayName, 
                    t.ticketTitle,
                    t.ticketDueDate,
                    t.ticketStatus,
                    t.ticketProblemType,
                    t.ticketAssignedTech,
                    t.ticketLastModifiedDate FROM `tickets` AS t 
                INNER JOIN `customers` AS c ON t.clientID = c.id 
                WHERE t.ticketStatus <> "closed"
                ORDER BY t.ticketDueDate ASC");
```

Comment: Missing `,` after column names starting from `t.ticketTitle` also you are using `"` as your string for the prepare so you need to put `'` around closed so it doesn't think you a closing the original string. E.g. `WHERE t.ticketStatus <> 'closed'`

Comment: wow, I'm dumb.  That should work.  Thanks.  If you want to set that as the answer i'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: If there is anything else wrong just let me know and we can see what to do :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `,` after column names starting from `t.ticketTitle`.

You are using `"` as your string for the prepare so you need to put `'` around `closed` so it doesn't think you a closing the original string. E.g. `WHERE t.ticketStatus <> 'closed'`

Answer (score 2):

For each column you are selecting the statement should be deliminated by a `,`. In addition, there are other syntax and semantic issues that are present, consult the error codes as they come and reference the docs. Before creating a join, I recommend getting the `table` formed separately so you can verify the tables are correct then do an `INNER JOIN`. Building a query is a step by step process.

In MySQL comparing `strings` should use `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE`
[MySQL Doc on String Comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

For reference, if you need additional syntax for queries consult the [MySql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)